Abrir gestor de correo con kotlin
tengo el siguiente código kotlin el cual me funciona perfectamente con un terminal con la versión de android 9 y SDK 28 pero que no me funciona con otro terminal más nuevo con android 14 y SDK 34, a ver si alguien puede decirme a qué es debido.
El código es el siguiente:
binding.buttonMail.setOnClickListener() {

          val email = "micorreo@gmail.com"
          val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
          data = Uri.parse("mailto:$email")
            }

            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                // La aplicación de Gmail no está instalada en el dispositivo
                // Puedes manejar este caso según tus necesidades
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se puede abrir la aplicación de correo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


 }



Actualmente, desde que compilas tu aplicación con Android 11 (nivel de API 30) o versiones posteriores,  para que funcione el intent android.intent.action.SENDTO, debes agregar la sección queries dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml, de otra forma no podrá funcionar.
   <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

Revisa Visibilidad de paquetes en Android

Solucionado, muchísimas gracias, no estaba al tanto de esta actualización, pensaba que debía de ser algo de permisos pero no había encontrado nada que hablara de esta actualización.
